# graphic bug in unity, messy background for dash and launcher

Tags: unity, launcher, unity-dash, desktop-background

Since the oneiric update, after some usage the dash and the launcher backgrounds (when open) become messy. Here you can [see a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8w5d.jpg):

[image]

Sometimes, I also noticed (don't know if it's a bug) that the dash shows the desktop behind, even if I have an application open. And also I noticed that when you change desktop background, the dash always shows the same background. This become evident when I use the wallpaper that change through the day.

Many thanks in advance!!

EDIT:
I will report the bug for sure.
Here you can see the "see-through" behaviour I was talking about. Is this a bug?
[image]

Comment: Actually it’s a bug. File it running in a terminal `ubuntu-bug unity` and follow the instructions.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! As @Fitoschido said, this question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 2):

I cannot give an explanation for the degrading of the dash and Launcher image but as for the Dash being a little bit see-through I say that it is supposed to be like that. See, this link to [Mark Shuttleworth's blog for August this year](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/date/2011/08).

Notice the heading Visual Refinements. Note this quote:

> Rather than a flat darkening, we’re introducing a wash based on the desktop colour. The dash thus adjusts to your preferred palette based on your wallpaper.

If you are experiencing something different to this, then the problem might be to do with the graphic card driver or even the graphic card itself.

Regards.